# Why autocorrelation of data lead to the lower estimation of standard error for coefficient?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation, standard-error

The problem is from [ISLR][1] Problem 5.R.R2. The data is [here](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/HumanitiesSciences/StatLearning/asset/5.R.RData).

> Consider the linear regression model of $y$ on $X_1$ and $X_2$. Next, plot the data using `matplot(Xy,type="l")`. Which of the following do you think is most likely given what you see?

The answer is:

> Our estimate of $s.e.(\beta^1$) is too low.

The explanation is:

> There is very strong autocorrelation between consecutive rows of the data matrix. Roughly speaking, we have about 10-20 repeats of every data point, so the sample size is in effect much smaller than the number of rows (1000 in this case).

But I could not understand it... According to my opinion, [image], the denominator of this equation (that used to calculate the estimation of standard error for coefficient) indicates no difference whether xi sequence is autocorrelated or not.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: They *meant* to say "very strong *positive* autocorrelation."  One way to understand it is to contemplate what happens when the autocorrelation equals $1$: there, you clearly have just one piece of information because the repeats don't add anything new.

Comment: Sorry for removing the link of ISLR because the website said that I need 10 reputation to add more than two links....